# Conditional directives for if IE >= 9 or not IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I am starting a new project and sadly I have to support IE7 & IE9. Eventually I will be able to remove IE7 support but would like a smooth way of removing it.

Essentially, where possible I want to be using the latest versions of libraries.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aFarkas/html5shiv/master/dist/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gte IE 9]>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json3/3.3.1/json3.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.17/angular.min.js"></script>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="local/angularjs-attribute-polyfill.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

As you can see, I have the JQuery library there twice, once of gte IE9 and once for not equal to IE for the other browsers...is there a nice way to consolidate these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
<!--[if gte IE 9]><!-->
    <script src="...jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

This conditional comment will allow the script to be included if using IE9 or higher... and non-IE browsers will ignore the comment anyway and just include the script, no questions asked.

Comment: Just a note here that conditional comments don't work on IE11

Comment: @crisbeto That's fine, because IE11 behaves like "not IE" as far as conditional comments are concerned ;)

Comment: FYI the jQuery blog documents how to do this: http://blog.jquery.com/2013/03/01/jquery-2-0-beta-2-released/